# PRUEBA DE PROGRAMA WEB JAVA

Tags: java, web, pruebas-unitarias

Buen día, me podrían apoyar en esto>
escenario: tengo una aplicación web hecho en java que la trabajo desde un equipo remoto, mi duda es como puedo hacer prueban para ingreso de sesión al mismo tiempo, he probado con dos navegadores distintos pero al acceder, el usuario final se superpone al usuario anterior, he estado intentando usar la ip del equipo remoto en mi equipo y colocar la url correspondiente (http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8080/miAplicacion/login.zul) pero no me funciona también he quitado el firewall para esta conexión pero tampoco funciona.

si alguno pudiera darme una idea para hacer las pruebas se los agradecería.

Comment: Hola Alejandro, estás por una VPN o tenes el equipo remoto dentro de la intranet?

Comment: Si, estoy conectado por una VPN con "check point endpoint security vpn".

Comment: Por si acaso, si estas trabajando en Windows fíjate si la carpeta donde está el proyecto tiene permisos de compartir su contenido. La verdad necesito más información para ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias, voy a revisar, alguna otra forma de poder realizar ese tipo de pruebas habrá?

Comment: La verdad que no le veo nada raro si estas con la VPN debería darte respuesta el servidor donde estás probando tu aplicación si ese servidor tiene el mismo rango de IP que los demás. También me parece un error de permios de redes. Por ejemplo acá en mi trabajo las computadoras normales tienen un rango de IP que es el 192.168.101.1 y los servidores tienen  192.168.110.0 y debemos pedir permisos de seguridad al Dpto. de Redes y Servidores para ingresar desde afuera.

Comment: Voy a ver todo lo del tema de permisos, Gracias.